# c#, matriz de objetos, ¿como verse mutuamente?

Tags: c#, objective-c, matrices-asociativas

estoy haciendo experimentos de redes neuronales. Por si no sabeis, hay pasos en que cada neurona, necesita VER parametros de otras, (* si, ya se, cada capa puede programarse como una matriz, y funciona, pero ahora quiero otro enfoque, ademas es un problema recurrente). .
Se me ocurrio hacer una classNeuro, y en ClassCerebro crea una matriz de neuronas. . `

```
    public class ClassCerebro
    {
        public string nomb;
        public static int nNeuros;
        public ClassNeuro[] Neuro; //habra una matriz de neuros
        public struct StructCerebroCrea
        {
            public string nomb;
            public int nNeuros;
        }
        public StructCerebroCrea structCerebroCrea = new StructCerebroCrea(); //estructura de creacion 

        public void Crea(StructCerebroCrea structCerebroCreaLoc)
        {
            nomb = structCerebroCreaLoc.nomb;
            nNeuros = structCerebroCreaLoc.nNeuros; //numero de neuros en cerebro

            Neuro = new ClassNeuro[nNeuros]; //CREA LA MATRIZ DE NEUROS
            for (int k = 0; k < nNeuros; k++) //para cada neuro 
            {
                Neuro[k] = new ClassNeuro();//CREA TRIPAS DE CADA NEURO, PERO NO LAS QUE ENTIENDE EN ClassNeuro
                Neuro[k].Crea(structCreaNeuro);
            }

        }
```

`
YA a la hora de desarrollar ClassNeuro.Hacer() tuve problemas para decir genericamente que esa neuro generica tiene que acceder a otra. .

```
public void Hacer()
    {
        if (esEntra) { return; }
        double preSTemp;
        preSTemp = 0;
        for (int ke = 0; ke < nEnt; ke++)
        {
            preSTemp += Neuro[entr[ke]].sale * coef[ke];//PROBLEMA, neuro NO ve las otras//error en ejecu, objeto Null.
        }
        preSTemp += offSet ,,,,;
```

De momento lo solucione con `

```
public class ClassNeuro
{
    public ClassNeuro[] Neuro; // ESTO, esto soluciona compilacion, muy feo

    public string nomb;
    public int nivel;
    public int nEnt;
    public int[] entr;
    public double[] coef;
    public void Hacer(){,,,};

`
```

La cosa no pinta bien, en ClassNeuro, se le dice que en cada una habra una matriz de neuros,
Y ciertamnete, aunque desde Cerebro se ve la matriz de neuros bien creada, al descender a una concreta en Neuro.Hacer(), en depuracion, dice error objeto no instanciado, Neuro[x] = null

¿Alguien sabe como?

Comment: "Parece" no es respuesta. Si no estás seguro, no respondas. Para sugerencias y recomendaciones, deja un comentario. – Candid Moe ayer.   ESTO me comento Candid, y tiene razon, esto es lo que habia escrito, lo borro como respuesta:  . . . . . .Parece que lo resolvi, quizas no sea lo ideal, ni lo mas elegante. Parece que cada Neuro[x] no puede ver a Neuro[y], un objeto "no puede ver" a sus hermanos. La solucion fue sacar las funciones que necesitan ver a sus hermanos y llevarlas al objeto que las contiene, él si puede ver todas. en mi caso Hacer(), ahora esta en Cerebro.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque hay un montón de *frameworks* para redes neuronales, tu pregunta me llamó la atención. ¿Por qué una neurona debe tener acceso al resto de las que están en la misma capa? Me pareció que sería más adecuado hacer varias abstracciones y llegué a un código, que es bastante primario, rudimentario, y poco elaborado. Te lo pongo aquí a modo de ejemplificar otra forma de hacerlo.

Los datos de inicialización en este código no tienen en cuenta ni el entrenamiento de la red ni nada más, son sólo a manera de mero ejemplo.

Hay una abstracción de Neurona (`Neuron`), una de Capa (`Layer`), otra de Red (`NeuronsNetwork`), y una utilitaria (`InputProvider`) para hacer el paso de los datos entre capas y entre la entrada y la primera capa. Los coeficientes de peso están representados en la clase `Synapsis`, representa la conexión entre una neurona de una capa y otra neurona de la capa precedente, con la entrada como es el caso de la capa de entrada.

No lo he tenido en cuenta en el código, pero en el método `Calculate` de la clase `Layer` se pueden aplicar otras técnicas para paralelizar los cálculos y hacer más rápida la red.

Para utilizar la red, de la forma en que la he ejemplificado aquí, sólo es necesario colocar los valores de entrada en la variable `Inputs`, como por ejemplo `Inputs.Clear(); Inputs.AddRange(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });`, luego invocar `Calculate` de la red (`Network.Calculate()`) y los datos de salida estarán disponibles a través del método `GetOutput` de la red (`ICollection<double> Output = Network.GetOutput();`).

No la he probado con valores reales de un modelo entrenado porque es sólo para ejemplificar una manera de crear las relaciones entre los elementos de la red. Espero que te sea útil.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface InputProvider
{
    double Value { get; }
}

public class DataFromArrayInputProvider : InputProvider
{
    public IReadOnlyList<double> Input { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public DataFromArrayInputProvider WithInput(IReadOnlyList<double> input)
    {
        Input = input;
        return this;
    }

    public DataFromArrayInputProvider WithIndex(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
        return this;
    }

    public double Value => Input[Index];
}

public class Synapsis
{
    public InputProvider Input { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Neuron : InputProvider
{
    public double Value { get; protected set; }
    public ICollection<Synapsis> Inputs { get; set; }
    public Func<double, double> ActivationFunction { get; set; }

    public Neuron WithActivationFunction(Func<double, double> activationFunction)
    {
        ActivationFunction = activationFunction;
        return this;
    }

    public Neuron WithInputs(ICollection<Synapsis> inputs)
    {
        Inputs = inputs;
        return this;
    }

    public virtual void Calculate()
    {
        double acc = 0;
        foreach (var syn in Inputs)
            acc += syn.Input.Value * syn.Weight;

        Value = ActivationFunction(acc);
    }


    public double GetValue() => Value;
}


public class Layer
{
    public ICollection<Neuron> Neurons { get; set; }

    public virtual void Calculate()
    {
        foreach (var neuron in Neurons)
            neuron.Calculate();
    }
}


public class NeuronsNetwork
{
    public IReadOnlyList<Layer> Layers { get; set; }

    public virtual void Calculate()
    {
        foreach (var layer in Layers)
        {
            layer.Calculate();
        }
    }

    public ICollection<double> GetOutput()
    {
        Layer outputLayer = Layers[Layers.Count - 1];
        return outputLayer.Neurons.Select(n => n.Value).ToArray();
    }
}


public class Program
{
    const int INPUT_LAYER_NEURONS_COUNT = 4;
    const int HIDDEN_LAYER_NEURONS_COUNT = 5;
    const int OUTPUT_LAYER_NEURONS_COUNT = 2;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Input
        List<double> Inputs = new List<double>();

        // Capa de entrada
        List<Neuron> InputLayerNeurons = new List<Neuron>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < INPUT_LAYER_NEURONS_COUNT; idx++)
        {
            // SIMPLIFICACIONES: 
            // - Cada neurona asociada a un único valor de entrada
            // - Todas con los mismos pesos y la misma función de activación
            // EN UNA APLICACIÓN REAL HABRÍA QUE INICIALIZAR LOS VALORES CORRECTAMENTE
            InputLayerNeurons.Add(new Neuron()
            {
                Inputs = new Synapsis[] {
                    new Synapsis()
                    {
                        Input = new DataFromArrayInputProvider() {Input = Inputs, Index = idx},
                        Weight = 0.5
                    }
                },
                ActivationFunction = v => v
            });
        }

        // Capa oculta
        List<Neuron> HiddenLayerNeurons = new List<Neuron>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < HIDDEN_LAYER_NEURONS_COUNT; idx++)
        {
            // SIMPLIFICACIONES: 
            // - Todas con los mismos pesos y la misma función de activación
            // EN UNA APLICACIÓN REAL HABRÍA QUE INICIALIZAR LOS VALORES CORRECTAMENTE
            HiddenLayerNeurons.Add(new Neuron()
            {
                Inputs = InputLayerNeurons.Select(n => new Synapsis() { Input = n, Weight = 0.5 }).ToArray(),
                ActivationFunction = v => v > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0
            });
        }

        // Capa de salida
        List<Neuron> OutputLayerNeurons = new List<Neuron>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < OUTPUT_LAYER_NEURONS_COUNT; idx++)
        {
            // SIMPLIFICACIONES: 
            // - Todas con los mismos pesos y la misma función de activación
            // EN UNA APLICACIÓN REAL HABRÍA QUE INICIALIZAR LOS VALORES CORRECTAMENTE
            OutputLayerNeurons.Add(new Neuron()
            {
                Inputs = HiddenLayerNeurons.Select(n => new Synapsis() { Input = n, Weight = 0.5 }).ToArray(),
                ActivationFunction = v => v > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0
            });
        }

        // Red
        NeuronsNetwork Network = new NeuronsNetwork()
        {
            Layers = new Layer[]
            {
                new Layer() {Neurons = InputLayerNeurons},
                new Layer() {Neurons = HiddenLayerNeurons},
                new Layer() {Neurons = OutputLayerNeurons}
            }
        };

        // Unos datos absurdos de entrada.
        Inputs.Clear();
        Inputs.AddRange(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });

        // Calcular y obtener el resultado.
        Network.Calculate();
        ICollection<double> Output = Network.GetOutput();

        // No hay nada que mostrar, el resultado de este programa será completamente irrelevante con 
        // los valores de inicialización dados aquí
        Console.Write( "No se muestran resultados, es de manera intensionada. Pulse una tecla para salir" );
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: bueno,,,  gracias por tus desvelos, pero la pregunta era: "en una matriz de objetos, ¿pueden y como VER uno en concreto los valores de los demas?", aun asi te has ganado el derecho a explicarte el por que de mi interes en neuronales, 1º aunque tengo que estudiarme mejor tu propuesta (no soy informatico de carrera, me da verguenza reconocer mi ignorancia incluso de palabras reservadas), me resultara instructiva. 2º ,,, sigo.

Comment: 2º basicamente, por lo que veo, ya he pasado por ahi, y decirte que la clase neurona la descarte muy al principio, porque hasta llegar a la activacion, lo que hace la neuro es resolver una fila de una matriz de las del cole, toda la capa es una matriz, (despues pasar por la activacion).  sigo,,,

Comment: 3º mi interes en volver a neurona, es probar arquit raras, por ejemplo: predecir el tiempo, me parece un error meter viento, T, Humedad, presion,,, de un mes , como datos brutos en la capa de entrada, son datos de distinta naturaleza, el viento deberia ir a una capita, la t a otra PARALELA, ,,, y cada dia a otra. La oculta veria a todas ellas. Y ademas queria hacer una arquit "selva", una matriz de neuros, cada una se engancha aleatoriamente a las inferiores, resulta que converge, pero con grandes variaciones, genera oscilaciones.  Y NO, no pretendia que las neuros de capa vean a sus vecinas.